# how to control users login on Linux machine according to configuration file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, authentication, ksh

I have Linux red-hat machine version 6.x

This machine is a server machine that serve many users ( 2000  diff users that login to this machine )

Login/password

```
  Login – root

  Password – Pass123
```

But on Some users I want to disable the login access

And all other users I want to enable the login access to the machine

As the following way

I want to create file - **/etc/logins_users.txt**

```
 #Users        disable/enable
 Uhdwe               0
 Hdec                0
 Tfsge               1
 Okdejb              0
 Wfdxdswh            1
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

- remark - User name is Uniq Name

So if user get value 0 then the access to the server is denied

but if value is 1 then users will login to the server

So the Question is how to disable/enable users login according to the file **/etc/logins_users.txt** ?

Comment: The usual way to manage this would be to disable their shell. `chsh -s /usr/sbin/nologin username`.  See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false

Comment: this example is about how to disable , but how to enable it  ?

Comment: Running with `-s ''` will enable the account by setting the shell to the system's default.  If you have users who used to have a different preferred shell, they'll have to change it back once they are able to login; or maybe you want to keep track of what the value was before you disabled it so that you can revert it later.

Comment: Ha - the problem is that user can work with diff shells as tcsh sh csh ksh bash , so it very problematic

Comment: Well, yes, so use your configuration file to keep track of what they had before you disabled it.  Or disable it by setting it to `/sbin/notksh` for `ksh`, etc.

Comment: but some times user work with other shells , for example user decided to work with diff shell , then his default

Comment: can you please see the manuel answer , I tested is but from some reason its not work as I explined there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PAM to authenticate, you may use the pam_listfile.so module to achieve this: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_listfile

Basically you create a file here e.g. /etc/logins_users.txt with content

```
user1
user2
user3
```

and in your PAM configuration for e.g. /etc/pam.d/sshd you need to add:

```
auth required pam_listfile.so item=user onerr=fail sense=allow file=/etc/logins_user.txt
```

Doing so allows all users specified in your file to login via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Append following names (directives):

```
DenyUsers User1 User2 WhatEverYouLike 
DenyGroups root finadmin WhatEverYouLike
```

Save, restart sshd

Comment: but if I have 1000 users to deny?

Comment: in this case I need to set 1000 users in one line ?

Comment: put all users to a group, DeniedUsersGroup or something else, and add the group name to sshd_config ... that's why I gave you both choices ... denyUsers and denyGroups ... so you can choose what is the best option for you

Comment: you only need to add the denied users (disable 0 as per your initial post). The users that are allowed, do not put them in sshd_config

Comment: sorry but - its not clear -:( , can you please re edit your post and described exactly waht need to set in files in order to disable user?

Comment: ok, let's take it one step at a time. How many users you need to allow and how many users you need to block?

Comment: user Uhdwe - allow and user Wfdxdswh is block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71564/discussion-between-maihabunash-and-candymanuu).